# MS Access / T-SQL - Grouping Interval Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, vba

I have some records in a csv file that are being loaded into a MS SQL Server 2016 table via a MS Access database. I'd like to group these records using either a VBA query or a T-SQL query (instead of VBA code using recordsets) before they are inserted into the SQL database table.

Example input:

```
ShiftID    Name_ID          From    To  Length  Size    Chargeable**
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
DAY1       CLASSIC_1        0.0     2.8  2.8    NQ2     Yes
DAY1       CLASSIC_1        2.8     5.8  3      NQ2     No
DAY1       CLASSIC_1        5.8     8.0  2.2    NQ2     No
DAY1       CLASSIC_1        8.0     11.1 3.1    NQ2     Yes
DAY1       CLASSIC_1        11.1    14.3 3.2    NQ2     Yes
```

Required Output:

```
ShiftID    Name_ID          From    To  Length  Size    Chargeable
----------------------------------------------------------------------
DAY1       CLASSIC_1        0.0     2.8  2.8     NQ2    Yes
DAY1       CLASSIC_1        2.8     8.0  5.2     NQ2    No
DAY1       CLASSIC_1        8.0    14.3  6.3     NQ2    Yes
```

Using the query:

```
SELECT ShiftID, Name_ID, Min([From]) AS [From], Max([To]) AS [To], Sum(Length) AS Length, 
Size, Chargeable FROM table1
 GROUP BY ShiftID, Name_ID, Size, Chargeable
 ORDER BY ShiftID, Name_ID, Min([From]), Max([To]), Size, Chargeable;
```

returns the following records:

```
ShiftID Name_ID     From    To   Length  Size   Chargeable
----------------------------------------------------------------
DAY1    CLASSIC_1   0.0     14.3  9.1    NQ2    Yes
DAY1    CLASSIC_1   2.8     8.0   5.2    NQ2    No
```

which is what I'd expect but not what I need. Grouping in this instance does not give me the correct *To* depth. The correct query should not return overlapping intervals.

Comment: Using just straight SQL, nothing comes to mind of the top of my head. I can only see using a cursor in a stored procedure in SQL Server, or VBA in Access to create a temp table by looping through results. Maybe someone else will see a more obvious solution that doesn't involve looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *gaps and islands* problem. Using the following T-SQL query:

```
SELECT ShiftID, Name_ID, [From], [To], Length, Size, Chargeable,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ShiftID, Name_ID, Size 
                          ORDER BY [From]) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ShiftID, Name_ID, Size, Chargeable
                          ORDER BY [From]) AS grp
FROM Table1
```

produces the following output:

```
ShiftID Name_ID     From  To    Length  Size    Chargeable  grp
---------------------------------------------------------------
DAY1    CLASSIC_1   3     5     3       NQ2     No          1
DAY1    CLASSIC_1   6     8     2       NQ2     No          1
DAY1    CLASSIC_1   0     2     3       NQ2     Yes         0
DAY1    CLASSIC_1   8     11    3       NQ2     Yes         2
DAY1    CLASSIC_1   11    14    3       NQ2     Yes         2
```

You now can use `grp` to consolidate the records:

```
SELECT ShiftID, Name_ID, Size, 
       MIN([From]) AS [From], MAX([To]) AS [To], SUM(Length) AS Length,
       Chargeable
FROM (
    SELECT ShiftID, Name_ID, [From], [To], Length, Size, Chargeable,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ShiftID, Name_ID, Size 
                              ORDER BY [From]) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ShiftID, Name_ID, Size, Chargeable 
                              ORDER BY [From]) AS grp
    FROM Table1) AS t
GROUP BY ShiftID, Name_ID, Size, Chargeable, grp
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/88dcf/1)

Comment: This works for me. Thanks Giorgos for posting this and letting me know about the correct terminology - gaps and islands.

Comment: @Kanga5 Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this or any other answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In *Access SQL* it can be done with subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    MeasureLevel.ShiftID,
    MeasureLevel.Name_ID,
    Min(MeasureLevel.From) AS [From], 
    Max(MeasureLevel.To) AS [To], 
    Sum(MeasureLevel.Length) AS Length, 
    MeasureLevel.Size,
    MeasureLevel.Chargeable
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Measure.ShiftID,
        Measure.Name_ID,
        Measure.From, 
        Measure.To, 
        Measure.Length, 
        Measure.Size,
        Measure.Chargeable, 
        (Select 
            Max(T.From) 
        From 
            Measure As T 
        Where 
            T.From <= Measure.To And 
            T.Chargeable = Measure.Chargeable) AS [Level]
    FROM 
        Measure) As MeasureLevel
GROUP BY 
    MeasureLevel.ShiftID,
    MeasureLevel.Name_ID,
    MeasureLevel.Level, 
    MeasureLevel.Size,
    MeasureLevel.Chargeable
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, it looks like this Access SQL query works where the Chargeable field changes. However, if the Chargeable field is the same for every record, then the records aren't grouped (the Level field is different for each of these records). But I get the idea of using sub-queries, so thanks for looking at this.